# Flutter: How to make a button invisible but active so that you can only see Text?

Tags: button, flutter, uibutton

```
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 92),
              child: RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                    );
                  },
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Forgot Password?",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(196, 135,
                          198, 1)),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
```

How would you go about making a button that is invisible so that the user would only see the text? Let's say, they forgot their account and press on the text which would refer them to a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FlatButton` may be what you're looking for. It is a regular button but only shows its child.

Answer (score 0):

**Use flat button instead of Raisedbutton** try below example

```
              FlatButton(   
                        child: Text(
                          "Forgot Password?",
                          style: your text style;
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Inkwell` widget to implement `onTap` event on `Text` or any widget.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Text(
    "Forgot Password?",
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(196, 135, 198, 1),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes FlatButton without any background color. The default is transparent. Just a child: Text()

[FlatButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since Flutter v1.26.0-18.0-pre FlatButton is deprecated.

Use [TextButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) instead.

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {}, 
    child: Text('Button Text')
)
```